# predict() in lmer not recognizing id variable

Tags: r, regression, predict, lme4, mixed-models

Following [this tutorial](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#predictions-andor-confidence-or-prediction-intervals-on-predictions), I want to use `predict()` so that I can pop in unique values of all my predictors and then get the predicted values for those unique values.

But I keep getting strange errors (see below). Is there possibly a fix to this?

```
library(lme4)

dat3 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/dat3.csv')

m4 <- lmer(math~pc1+pc2+discon+(pc1+pc2+discon|id), data=dat3)

newdata <- with(dat3, expand.grid(pc1=unique(pc1), pc2=unique(pc2), discon=unique(discon)))

predict(m4, newdata=newdata)

#### ERROR:
Error in model.frame.default(tt, newdata.NA, na.action = na.pass, xlev = orig.random.levs) : 
  invalid type (closure) for variable 'id'
```

[image]

Comment: that excel sheet snapshot seems kind of useless since you've provided your data anyway ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a value for the random effects in your prediction data frame. To get population-level predictions (ignoring the random effects), use

```
predict(m4, newdata=newdata, re.form=NA)
```

You're getting a weird error message because you have a package loaded (probably `dplyr`) which has an `id()` function defined: if you didn't, you would get the more interpretable error message

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'id' not found

Comment: Ben, would you mind taking a look at this [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64978966/plotting-the-predictions-of-a-mixed-model-as-a-line-in-r)?