# Plotting the predictions of a mixed model as a line in R

Tags: r, plot, regression, lme4, mixed-models

I'm trying to plot the predictions (`predict()`) of my mixed model below such that I can obtain my conceptually desired plot as a line below.

I have tried to plot my model's predictions, but I don't achieve my desired plot. Is there a better way to define `predict()` so I can achieve my desired plot?

```
library(lme4)

dat3 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/dat3.csv')

m4 <- lmer(math~pc1+pc2+discon+(pc1+pc2+discon|id), data=dat3)

newdata <- with(dat3, expand.grid(pc1=unique(pc1), pc2=unique(pc2), discon=unique(discon)))

y <- predict(m4, newdata=newdata, re.form=NA)

plot(newdata$pc1+newdata$pc2, y)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `sjPlot`? It's great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More `sjPlot`. See the parameter `grid` to wrap several predictors in one plot.

```
library(lme4)
library(sjPlot)
library(patchwork)

dat3 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/dat3.csv')

m4 <- lmer(math~pc1+pc2+discon+(pc1+pc2+discon|id), data=dat3) # Does not converge

m4 <- lmer(math~pc1+pc2+discon+(1|id), data=dat3) # Converges

# To remove discon
a <- plot_model(m4,type = 'pred')[[1]]
b <- plot_model(m4,type = 'pred',title = '')[[2]]

a + b
```

[image]

Edit 1: I had some trouble removing the `dropcon` term within the `sjPlot` framework. I gave up and fell back on `patchwork`. I'm sure Daniel could knows the correct way.

Comment: Magnus, another problem is that the y-axes need to be on common scale so that a visual comparison between the plots is possible.

Comment: Use `ylim()` on both to align the axis. For example `+ ylim(0,2.5)`

Answer (score 0):

As Magnus Nordmo suggest, this is very simple with [`sjPlot`](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/plot_marginal_effects.html) which has some predefined functions for these types of plot.

```
library(lme4)

dat3 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/dat3.csv')

m4 <- lmer(math~pc1+pc2+discon+(pc1+pc2+discon|id), data=dat3)

plot_model(m4, type = 'pred', terms = c('pc1', 'pc2'),
           ci.lvl = 0)
```

which gives the following result.

[image: so-plot]

This plot is designed to include different quantiles of the second term in `terms` over the axes of `pc1` and `pred`. You could split up these plots and combine them using `patchwork` and the interval can be changed by using square brackets after the term in `terms` (eg `pc1 [-10:1]` for interval between -10 and 1).